# Python Spotify API - Unable to get full playlist with "get_playlist_items" method

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

When I want to extract all songs from a spotify playlist, I get only the first 100 songs even when using the "offset" and "limit" parameters in my get request. I'm using no libraries like spotipy and I'm working in Python 3.9.

Can someone please help me with what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

I use a function wherein I specify the parameters and the get request.

```
def find_songs(self):
self.params = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.spotify_token),
    "offset": 50,
    "limit": 50
    }


    query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}/tracks/".format(<playlist_URI>)
    response = requests.get(query, params=self.params)
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    jsonResponseItems = jsonResponse['tracks']['items']
```

I then extract the total number of numbers in playlist and then extend the responseItems because it's limited to 100 songs.

```
while len(jsonResponseItems) < jsonResponse['tracks']["total"]:

# len(jsonResponseItems)) # this returns 100
response = requests.get(query, params=self.params)
query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}/tracks?".format(<playlist_URI>)

newResponse = response.json() # create a new JSON response
jsonResponseItems.extend(newResponse['tracks']['items']) # extend JSON response items
```

What am I missing?
Docs: [https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-playlists-tracks](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You seem to be able to get the first two pages of the playlist (2*50). You should iterate in a while loop, incrementing offset by 50 each step, until the response doesn't contain any item.

Answer (score 1):

This code will address to get more than 100 songs.

Main idea as mentioned `Tranvi` is while loop keep request tile next URL is None.

This is format of next filed if still more song after calling get playlist API. the offset is automatically filed by response of data.

```
 "next": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/<playlist id>/tracks?offset=100&limit=100",
```

```py
import requests
import json

class MySong:
    CLIENT_ID = '<your client ID>'
    CLIENT_SECRET = '<your client Secret>'

    def __init__(self):
        self.get_token()

    def get_token(self):
        response = requests.post(url='https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                                 data={ 'grant_type': 'client_credentials' },
                                 auth=(self.CLIENT_ID, self.CLIENT_SECRET))
        self.spotify_token = response.json()['access_token']
        
    def find_songs(self, playlist_id):
        headers = {
            'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(self.spotify_token)
        }
        songs=[]
        url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}'.format(playlist_id)
        while True:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            results = response.json()
            newResponse = None
            
            if (results.get("items",None) is not None):
                newResponse = results['items']
            elif (results.get("tracks",None) is not None):
                newResponse = results['tracks']['items']
            
            for item in newResponse:
                if (item is not None):
                    songs.append({
                        'id' : item['track']['id'],
                        'name': item['track']['name'],
                        'url': item['track']['external_urls']['spotify'],
                        'album_name': item['track']['album']['name'],
                        'artists': item['track']['artists'][0]['name']
                    })
            if (results.get("next",None) is not None):
                url = results['next']
            elif (results.get("tracks",None) is not None):
                url = results['tracks']['next']
            else:   # no more songs
                break
        return songs

playlist_id = '<your playlist id>' # more than 700 songs playlist
my_song = MySong()
songs = my_song.find_songs(playlist_id)

print(json.dumps(songs[:3], indent=2)) # print fisrt 3 songs

print(json.dumps(songs[-3:], indent=2)) # print last 3 songs
print(len(songs)) # print total number of songs
```

Result - get more than 700 songs
[image]

It matched Spotify UI.
[image]