# New method required for adding tracks to a Spotify Playlist (from Windows command line)

Tags: curl, command-line-interface, spotify, bearer-token, playlist

on Windows 10...
Just this March (and for years prior) I was able to add items to my Spotify playlists using successive curl commands from the command line as follows (sans carriage returns). It was cool because I could add any number of tracks to a playlist from a simple script file (bat)
(... albeit, with some included pauses and some escape characters)

```
curl -X "POST" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/my-playlist-id/tracks? uris=spotify%3Atrack%3A0P7DoyGrr4Wp9w5TotEtUC" 
-H "Accept: application/json" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Content-length: 0" 
-H "Authorization: **Bearer bearer-id-obtained-by-requesting-token-from-spotify-api-demo-web-page-with-necessary-scopes**"
```

That once-familiar web interface (image below) for obtaining tokens isn't there now  <s>but it appears I can successfully obtain a token (?Bearer?) as follows... no problem:</s>

```
REMOVED: this question isn't really about what I have tried (which failed).
```

What I'd really like to understand is how to reproduce the very simple interface that once existed at developer.spotify.com under CONSOLE (as in the attached image).  Understand the following...

Below is an image of how easy it had been to get an appropriate token in the old interface. One would click GET TOKEN and this would display choices of your desired scope(s).  Select scopes as desired and it would take you back to the page with the GET TOKEN button,  but with a usable Bearer token filled in.  That token would be valid for the next hour.  Then you would need a new one.  Which was fine.

With that token I could execute any number of curl commands in CLI for adding items to a playlist.

From suggested reading this sounds like the "implicit grant flow".  I get that it's not recommended... which is probably why Spotify removed that Console interface.  But I want to reproduce it.

Everything I read seems to imply I now need my own web server to do that (albeit localhost)... all of which makes some sense, since I HAD previously been doing this on Spotify's.  And I suppose I can do that (PITA).  I have operated web servers and developed database apps on them.

It's the details of what code to place on that web server that have me baffled.  About three layers deep in the overview kindly pointed to in Bench Vue's reply there is [this](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-examples/tree/master/authentication/implicit_grant). Scope is mentioned once in the example.  Is it perhaps as simple as modifying "var scope" to list (instead) the scopes required for adding tracks to playlists?

P.S. Take it easy on this retired 70-year old who only USED TO do cool, complex things on web servers, and has forgotten much.

```
    localStorage.setItem(stateKey, state);
    var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';

    var url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
    url += '?response_type=token';
    url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(client_id);
    url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scope);
    url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri);
    url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);
```

[Previous web interface] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAQTB.png)

Comment: No you can't do it by `curl` due to [Add Items to Playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/add-tracks-to-playlist) required `Authorization code flow`. It can get access token by redirect URI by HTTP server. To exchange from Spotify server the `code`  into get an access token. By `curl` can do only `Client Credentials Flow`. the detailed information in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization)

Comment: Thank you Bench Vue.  I have revised my question to make it a bit clearer what I'm really seeking.  (May be too much.  Not sure.)

Comment: Again, your success to add a track(song) into playlist with access-token. That token made by [Developer Web](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/add-tracks-to-playlist). That token comes from your logged-in with your ID. It means already `Authorization code flow` did by Web. The curl only cannot make that kind of token(user information). Without web login, the curl cannot do to add song.

Comment: As clarified in my edited question... I am NOT looking for a way to use curl to obtain a Bearer token.

Comment: P.S. The curl output generated in the Developer Web is tantalizing similar to the previous output pictured in my attached image (from the developer "Console"... however the token generated is masked (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer 1POdFZRZbvb...qqillRxMr2z' ...notice ellipses) and therefore cannot be tested as useable within my curl commands in CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you and me comments communication was limited So I would like to explain in here.

This is demo overview how to success to add a track(song) into playlist?

The left side is `Client Credentials Flow` method

The right side is `Authorization Code Flow` method

Only the right side is possible to add.
The left side can't do it.

[image]

#### Client Credentials Flow

I will explain the left first.

I will use this track

```
https://open.spotify.com/track/4YCnTYbq3oL1Lqpyxg33CU
```

[image]

I will use this playlist  (hide playlist id due to private)

[image]

#### #1 Curl

From Terminal

Set environment variables with credential

```
CLIENT_ID='<your client id>'
CLIENT_SECRET='<your client secret>'
PLAYLIST_ID='<your playlist id>'
TRACK_ID='4YCnTYbq3oL1Lqpyxg33CU'
CLIENT_ID_SECRET=$(echo -n $CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET | base64 -w 0)
```

#### #2 Get `Access Token`

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic '$CLIENT_ID_SECRET \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' --data-urlencode 'scope=playlist-modify-private,playlist-modify-public'| jq -r '.access_token')
echo 'ACCESS_TOKEN = '$ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Will be display `Access Token` like this

[image]

#### #3 Add a track into the playlist

```
curl --location 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/'$PLAYLIST_ID'/tracks' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$ACCESS_TOKEN \
--data '{
    "uris": [
        "spotify:track:4YCnTYbq3oL1Lqpyxg33CU"
    ]
}'
```

Will be shows error (403) like this

[image]

So this method can't add a track due to `Client credentials Flow` not allowing to add a song.

#### Authorization Code Flow

Save `get-token.js`

```js
const express = require("express")
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

CLIENT_ID = "<your client id>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client secret>"
PORT = 3000 // it is located in Spotify dashboard's Redirect URIs, my port is 3000
REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback` // my case is 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
SCOPE = [
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'playlist-modify-private'
]
const PLAY_LIST_ID = 'your playlist ID' // your playlist ID

const getToken = async (code) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            data = new URLSearchParams({
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
                'code': code
            }),
            config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: CLIENT_ID,
                    password: CLIENT_SECRET
                }
            })
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data.access_token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }
}

app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPE}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
})

app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const code = request.query["code"]
    getToken(code)
        .then(access_token => {
            return response.send({'access_token': access_token});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`)
})
```

#### install dependencies

```
npm install express axios cors
```

[image]

#### Run express server

```
node get-token.js
```

[image]

#### #4 Get Token

#### Open the Browser and login with this URL

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

The browser login then turns into redirect and shows `access token`
Copy only the value of the `token` into the clipboard.

[image]

```
ACCESS_TOKEN1="Paste access token from Browser in here"
```

[image]

#### #5/#6 Add track with the new token

```
curl --location 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/'$PLAYLIST_ID'/tracks' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$ACCESS_TOKEN1 \
--data '{
    "uris": [
        "spotify:track:4YCnTYbq3oL1Lqpyxg33CU"
    ]
}'
```

[image]

[image]

##### Conclusion

From this demo, the `authorization code flow` can add a song by curl.

even if the `client credentials flow` cannot.

I have no experience `implicit flow` so I have no idea it can do or cannot.

Comment: This is so very thorough (just what I need).  Thank you so much.  I am almost at the end of a different project.  So I expect I will be able to give your example full attention soon.  It looks like I will have to work through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows) as a prerequisite but I'm sure that won't be a problem.
Again thank you...

Comment: No problem, I hope to success to reproduce my steps. If you like me answer, feel to accept my answer. it will give me 15 points. Thanks!

Comment: You needs to install node.js from [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download) , 64 bits Windows Installer (.msi)

Comment: Success!  I will detail a couple small issues I had with node.js installation, which could help others.  But without your steps I would remain lost.  Again many thanks.

On:
 installation I got:
WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell
If I had heeded that I may not have had the following.

Comment: Happy to hear you got it. Good luck for other parts.

Comment: "The following" being...   npm install express  npm install axios   npm install cors  Then after that, I got:  

Listening on :3000  
YEAH!

Comment: And of course, logon and adding tracks was smooth after that.

Comment: Good,  `node.js` is very simple and powerful, there are a bunch of libraries, I love it.

Comment: I answered many other examples for Spotify by node.js and python. You can leverage it.